# How I can show/hide view inside another view with height changing of root swift?

Tags: swift, resize

I have two views one inside another, it looks like picture below:

[image]

when I press on orange arrow I would like to show/hide view above grey line and grey line too. I did it by such way:

```
@objc func showHide(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
        let tappedImage = tapGestureRecognizer.view as! UIImageView
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.jobDataView.isHidden = !self.jobDataView.isHidden
            
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
        
        tappedImage.image = self.jobDataView.isHidden ? UIImage(systemName: "arrow.down"):UIImage(systemName: "arrow.up")
    }
```

and my view above gray line can be hidden and shown. But root view doesn't change its' height and it has similar sizes before and after btn click. I tried to add constraint of height, but I it didn't solve my problem. Maybe someone knows how to solve my problem?

Comment: use stackview, when you hide subview inside stackview it will automatically change stackview height

Comment: I don'e use swiftui, does stack view will help me in ordinary storyboard?

Comment: @Andrew as you say`I tried to add the constraint of height`, are you also updating height of root view after `layoutIfNeeded()`?

Comment: @KishanBhatiya, I tried to change height constraint but it didn't give any visible result

Comment: UIstackview is not swiftUI, i often use it in ordinary storyboard too

Comment: @aiwiguna, and how I can hide subview? Like I did it above?

Comment: yes,u can have a IBOutlet for the subview and set isHidden to true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `UIStackView` either through `Storyboard` or from code.  when you hide subview inside `stackview` it will automatically change `stackview` height. what you need to do is to make stackView `distribution = fill` and use vertical stack...
Hide view on button tap and when you need to show it .. add it in stack at. `0th` index ..

[image]